# ValueError: Input contains NaN

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I'm having this kind of error and I really don't know what to do, please help me out with this it's say NaN which I dont have an idea what it it
[image]

Comment: Have a look [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ask). Try to [make an honest attempt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) at solving the problem yourself, and then please feel free to ask specific questions about your solution, or problems with it. ([and don't post code/errors/data as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question))

Comment: you need to get rid of nan, what is your data ? dataframe ?

Comment: yes dataframe @khaled-koubaa

Answer (score 2):

You can use the imputation function from sklearn to fill nan values.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
values = imp.fit([[1, 2], [np.nan, 3], [7, 6]])
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to get rid of infinite and null values.
try:

```
df = df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).fillna(99999)

#or
df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).dropna() 

#if needed:
df = df.reset_index()
```